# AzureBlobStorage and AzureBlobTranscriptStore error after updating Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure nuget to 4.4.3

Tags: botframework

Compile error encountered on both **AzureBlobStorage** and **AzureBlobTranscriptStore** was

> reference to type 'cloudstorageaccount' claims it is defined in 'microsoft.azure.storage.common', but it could not be found

What I did to make my code compile was to clone Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure then update all references from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.* to Microsoft.Azure.Storage.* counterparts.

Is it just a matter of time until Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure is updated so this error doesn't appear?

For reference, image below shows Mirosoft.Bot.Builder.Azure's AzureBlobStorage class referencing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage instead of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.

[image]

The similar questions to mine were resolved by removing csproj reference to  Microsoft.WindowsAzure. I don't have such reference in my project.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1686 related issue